# How to get all references which hinders delete of a row I'm trying to delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Sql-Server database (2008R2, if that is important) with lots of tables.
Some table contains foreign key references to other tables, and some of the foreign key constraints have cascade on delete, and some are restricted delete.

To be user friendly, in my application I want to figure out all other references that needs to be deleted before I can delete the one I'm currently deleting and present it to the user.
Some generic problems described below:

1. I try to delete from Customer where Id = 1 and Order has a foreign key to Customer (and that foreign key restricts user from deleting customer before orders are deleted), I would want to get a result of all Orders that restricts me from deleting Customer.
2. If Contracts have references to Customer as well, and that foreign key is cascade, but Contract is referenced by Alarm with restricted delete, I want to get which Contract was responsible for not being able to delete Customer, and also the Alarms which was responsible for not being able to delete Customer.
3. I want this behavior to be recursive, so that I get all connections, direct or indirect which hindered me from deleting Customer in the first place. I also want to be able to get this information wherever I start (No matter if I wanted to delete a Customer, Order, Alarm etc)

It feels like someone aught to have had similar problems before me, but I can mostly find information to get table->table foreign key restrictions, not in relation to a specific entity in the database (i.e. customer with Id = 1)

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: There's nothing built in that I'm aware of. It could be phenomenally expensive to compute the transitive closure over all FK references in a database of any decent size. That's why the server gives up immediately when it hits the first obstacle.

Comment: This is **precisely** what you should **not** do. You should **never** just automatically remove rows. You should **always** have a known relationship with those rows and do an informed decision whether those rows should be deleted or not. You, the programmer, not the user, and certainly not the program. If a row *should* prevent the master row from being deleted, a "figure it out and just do it" will walk around that. Additionally, to delete those other rows, you might have to delete other rows other places, etc. etc. My advice: **don't do it!**

Comment: If the database is correctly designed, it should be possible for you to obtain only the direct relationship to the entity to be deleted. That is, if you can't delete the customer because of orders placed by this customer, then that should be a 'friendly enough' reason to send back to the customer without having to go in more detail.

Comment: @EmmadKareem That might have been OK, but for us (with the legacy we do have), we have table structures that are up to 7+ dependencies deep. So sure, the user gets information that it needs to delete it's orders, but when it tries to delete orders, he gets information that something else needs to be deleted first, and when trying to delete that he...... gets more information about stuff needed to be deleted.

Comment: No there isn't any easy way.

Comment: Um well you know how to find the dependancy chains so it's just a question of creating and running queries that will check to see if they exist for that record. Sounds simple when you say it quick doesn't it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm not trying to delete everything for the user, I want to present all information to the user of what he needs to delete before he will be able to delete the entity he is currently trying to delete. So I will put the effort on the user to do the actual deleting, but I want to be gracious enough to tell him everything when he tries to delete something, so that he doesn't have to go all over the place before he finally gets to the leaf element. And from the list of restrictions, he might be able to realize that it was a bad idea to remove something in the first place.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yeah, that sounds easy enough when you have a small set of tables and data to go through. We have 1000+ tables with different degrees of dependencies, and if there were a way to go about this problem in a general way, it might save enormous amounts of time and code to get the problem solved.

Comment: Indeed. Consider yourself lucky. I get to deal with a legacy db where the relations can't (polymorphic but not) or aren't defined, so I have to maintain a class that "knows" the dependencies from an application perspective and does all the necessary deletes in a oner. :( There's always someone worse off. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Well... tbh, we have those kinds of relations as well, but I'd rather have a general way for the first 95% and then write the special cases manually afterwards. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically I look at this as part of database/application architecture and you need to know as the developer or DBA how you tables are connected.

You need to use the customer ID and query against any table that uses customerID as a foreign key and that would give you a result.same with the contracts.   You can do this with some ERD tools, but I tend to make my own classes to do this for my databases, this way I have total control of what I want to do.  For instance in the delete method for a customer, a company may just want to disable or set active to false for the customer.  or truly delete everything.

There is a way to cascade deletion in the database, but I am not sure you want to do that, since you are asking for a result to be returned.

Comment: We do not want to use cascade delete for everything. Some things are OK to cascade, but some things we need to get the user input, since the user might not be aware of the consequences of deleting certain things. But we do not want to set the user out on a wild goose chase, trying to delete customer -> Get error that it has orders -> Try to delete an Order -> Get errors that order is connected somewhere else...

Comment: Then I would recommend setting up a class the would return a dataset that you could display this information to the user.

Comment: The problem is not to show the information to the user, that I will figure out. The problem is finding the information in the first place. When you try to delete something in SQL, you receive the first error to occur, not the entire dependency structure. I want the user to be able to see the entire dependency graph when he tries to delete a specific entity.